# How can I take command input using php with shell_exec()

Tags: javascript, php, c++, http

I am working on a project that takes users c++ code as input and compiles it from the server and sends the output to the user.

But here, If the c++ code has something like taking input from the user then that time my code fails. I want to do something from which I can take users input also on my website.

This is my php code -

```
<?php $code = $_POST['code']; if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){

$md5hash = md5($code);

$filename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/code/" . $md5hash . ".cpp";   
$filexe= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/code/" . $md5hash . ".exe";

$dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/code';


//this will make the directory if the directory is not present
if ( !file_exists($dir) )
{
    mkdir ($dir, 0777);
}

$myfile = fopen($filename,"w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile,$code);  //Store the user submitted code into a file
fclose($myfile);

$command1 = "C:\TDM-GCC-32\bin\g++ " . $filename . " -o ". $filexe;
$output1 = shell_exec($command1 . " 2>&1"); 
$output = shell_exec($filexe . " 2>&1");    
$input = 

if(empty($output1)){    
    echo $output;
}else echo $output1; } ?>
```

This is my index.php code

```
<center><textarea name="code" id="code" placeholder="Enter your C++ source code here.. " rows="15" cols="100%" style="padding:10px;font-size:18px"></textarea></center>
<center><button onclick="runcode();" style="cursor:pointer;padding:5px;display:flex;align-content:center;text-decoration:none;justify-content:space-around;background:brown;color:white;width:50%;">Run code</button>
```

## Output -

```
<div>
<center><textarea placeholder="waiting.... " rows="15" cols="100%" style="padding:10px;font-size:18px" id="out"></textarea></center>
</div>

<center><a href="#" style="cursor:pointer;padding:5px;display:flex;align-content:center;text-decoration:none;justify-content:space-around;background:brown;color:white;width:50%;">Fix Bug on this code!</a>
```

```
<?php include 'components/_footer.php' ?>

<script>
    function runcode(){

        document.getElementById('myoutput').setAttribute("class","show");
        
        $codevalue= document.getElementById('code').value;
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.onload = function(){
        const serverResponse = document.getElementById("out");
        serverResponse.innerHTML = this.responseText;
        };

        xhr.open("POST","runcode.php");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhr.send("code="+$codevalue);
    } 

    
</script>
```

I search on internet but couldn't find a better solution please help me to take the input from the user and showing the output to user also user should be able to put there input incase some program ask for user input

[image: Screenshot of output]

Comment: Since the C++ code would run on the server during the HTTP request, it cannot be interactive with a remote user - the browser will not receive anything back until the HTTP request has completed. The browser has no direct interaction with the C++ code or even the PHP code, it merely sends a HTTP request to the webserver and waits for a response. So you'd have to either collect all the user input up-front and write the C++ script in such a way that this info goes in as command-line parameters...

Comment: ...or you'd have to have a system where the script ends the C++ and PHP and returns to the browser, asks for the required input, the browser then sends that back to the server which triggers another script to continue processing until more input is required. Much like a web application which has a series of forms or whatever. What you're trying to do with an interactive session _within_ the C++ code is fundamentally incompatible with a web application architecture. You should conceptually see it that the PHP and C++ code are effectively running unattended on the server without any user session

Comment: @ADyson Thats actually what I want to do, I want to ask for the required input, then browser will send that input back to the server and it should trigger to the command and same thing happens until more input is required. As you said it might need series of forms.  This is my actual requirement but I am having trouble on doing this. Can you please help me with the programming logic how I can do this? And this should be done using c++ and php only thats why can you help me with logic? I searched whole internet and couldn't find the solution :( I think you can get me out of thing

Comment: That's a bit broad for a single stackoverflow answer, sorry. Break the task down into smaller parts and ask if you get stuck in a particular aspect.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you very much adyson, The first thing I am having problem is how can I track that the g++ compiler is expecting for users input ? How can I track that? that is the big problem I am facing if I could track that then I could run another function and that takes the input of users and sends back to the server on a single http request and response?

Comment: Well TBH you're going to have to make the user submit lots of small C++ programs to you, each of which is self-contained and executable by itself, because the only point at which you can feed user input to it is on the command-line when it starts. You'll notice that almost all online sandboxes similar to this (such as https://3v4l.org/ which is a PHP editor) have the same limitation, because of the architecture of the web. They cannot accept input mid-stream. So you don't need to detect anything like that, because it would be impossible to service a mid-program input anyway.

Comment: Another option is to completely re-think this, and use a front-end based solution such as http://cpp.sh/ has where it's primarily JavaScript driven, but also with some websocket communication. I can't see precisely how it works as the JS code is obfuscated, but it manages to create the ability to execute interactive C++ sessions. At a guess maybe it compiles it on the server and then executes it via a JS-based C++ runtime in the browser, or something. Otherwise I'm not quite sure how it could be done.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you very much adyson :) I applied some js to detect the input field and then compiled it with some logics. If you are interested you can view my compiler here = https://helpmy.codes/compile.php

Thank you for your time I highly appreciate